# Camera icon comes in and goes off weirdly

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

As per title, my Camera system icon comes in and goes off almost immediately. However, when I try to navigate to another screen, it stays there permanently.

Video of how it disappears.
https://vid.me/ggk5

My codes are as below. I've set my view controller as a delegate of `UINavigationControllerDelegate`. So when the imagepickercontroller is shown, I want to add a camera icon as per the video. However it comes in and goes off.

```
public func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, didShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool){
        let camera = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .camera, target: self, action: #selector(CameraTabTVC.btnOpenCamera))
        viewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = camera
    }

    func btnOpenCamera(){
        self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.delegate = self
        picker.sourceType = .camera
        picker.allowsEditing = true

        present(picker, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: where is your  `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` method?.You dont need to  `dismiss` pickerView? in `btnOpenCamera()`

Comment: yes I do have, but it has nothing related to my current issue. Because my issue is even before `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` or dismiss picker. The problem here is when displaying the photolibrary controller, the camera icon disappears.

Comment: Call  'willShow' method rather 'didShow' this way the navController display a VC after. Try let me know....

Comment: Tried. Same result.